# Fourth-Level Subdomain Forwarding

Tags: nginx

I've recently been trying to set up a reverse proxy that would forward certain 4th-level subdomains to particular locations. So, for example, this is what I'm trying to accomplish (configuration in my nginx file):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.server.domain.com;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

The goal here being that if someone went to, for example, http://item1.server.domain.com, they would be re-routed to https://item1.server.domain.com. However, with this configuration, the URL gets rewritten to https://%2A.server.domain.com.

Is there a way to fix this so that the full domain (item1) gets added correctly to the rewritten URL? Ideally, I wanted it to eventually be able to rewrite any subdomain on server.domain.com directly to https.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `$host` instead of `$server_name`.

Comment: Have tried that as well, with the same results. Still get redirected to https://%2A.server.domain.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$server_name` variable contains the text from the value of the `server_name` directive. The `%2A` is a URL encoded representation of the leading `*`.

Use `$host` or `$http_host` to obtain the hostname actually requested by the client. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) for more.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.server.domain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Note: Restart `nginx` and **clear the browser cache** between each test. Check the configuration using `nginx -T`.